# Turn Button into Picker

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have this code, where there are three buttons which have values stored in each of them.

When I press the `Add` button, the values add up and appear on the list. However, I am not able to check which values are being selected.

How can I make the button look like a picker, so that when the user clicks the button `A`, `B`, or `C`, it will show with a checkmark that it has been selected and when the user taps the `Add` button, the value of the selected button and `"gp"` should show up on the list? Also, the checkmark should disappear once the `Add` button is selected so that the user can select another list.

Such as:

- If A and B are selected, the list should look like:

> A = 2.0, B = 5.0, gp = 7.0.

- If A and C are selected, the list should look like:

> A= 2.0, C = 7.0, gp = 9.0.

I have tried using `Picker` and other methods, however, I couldn't get through. I have found this as the best solution. However, I am not able to put a checkmark on the buttons and not able to show the selected values on the list.

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainView: View {

    @State var br = Double()
    @State var loadpay = Double()
    @State var gp : Double = 0
    @State var count: Int = 1
    @State var listcheck = Bool()
    @StateObject var taskStore = TaskStore()
    @State var a = 2.0
    @State var b = 5.0
    @State var c = 7.0
   
    //var userCasual = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "userCasual") as? String ?? ""
    @State var name = String()
   
    func addNewToDo() {
       taskStore.tasks.append(Task(id: String(taskStore.tasks.count + 1), toDoItem:  "load \(gp)", amount: Double(gp)))
       self.gp = 0.0
    }

    func stepcount() {
       count += 1
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: { gp += a }) {
               Text("A =").frame(width: 70, height: 15)
                  .foregroundColor(.yellow)
            }  
            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5))
            .foregroundColor(.black)

            Button(action: { gp += b }) {
               Text("B =") .frame(width: 70, height: 15)
                  .foregroundColor(.yellow)
            }
            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5))
            .foregroundColor(.black)

            Button(action: { gp += c }) {
               Text("C =").frame(width: 70, height: 15)
                  .foregroundColor(.yellow)
             }
             .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5))
             .foregroundColor(.black)
        }

        HStack(spacing: 15) { 
           Button(
              String(format: ""), 
              action: { 
                 print("pay for the shift is ")
                 gp += loadpay
              }
           )

           Button(
              action: {
                 addNewToDo()
                 stepcount()
              },  
              label: { Text("Add")}
           )
        }

     Form {
        ForEach(self.taskStore.tasks) { task in
            Text(task.toDoItem)
        }
     }
   }
}

struct Task : Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = ""
    var toDoItem = ""
    var amount = 0.0
}

class TaskStore : ObservableObject {
    @Published var tasks = [Task]()
}
```

Comment: @lorem ipsum, didn't get what you mean. I want to make the button look like a picker, so that when I click on the button it selects and the when I press the add button, it adds up the selected button and prints them on the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are trying to turn a `Button` into something it is not. You can create your own view that responds to a tap and keeps its state so it knows whether it is currently selected or not. An example is this:

```
struct MultiPickerView: View {
    
    @State private var selectA = false
    @State private var selectB = false
    @State private var selectC = false
    
    let A = 2.0
    let B = 5.0
    let C = 7.0
    
    var gp: Double {
        (selectA ? A : 0) + (selectB ? B : 0) + (selectC ? C : 0)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                SelectionButton(title: "A", selection: $selectA)
                SelectionButton(title: "B", selection: $selectB)
                SelectionButton(title: "C", selection: $selectC)
            }
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            Text(gp.description)
                .padding()
        }
    }
}

struct SelectionButton: View {

    let title: String
    @Binding var selection: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: selection ? "checkmark.circle" : "circle")
            Text(title)
        }
        .padding()
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 4)
        )
        .padding()
        .onTapGesture {
            selection.toggle()
        }

    }
}
```

You could make it more adaptable by using an `Array` that has a struct that keeps the value and selected state, and run it though a `ForEach`, but this is the basics of the logic.